# How to Autostart Youtube VIDEO with Low Volume (iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

This is the iframe I create to autostart a video (music, mostly) in my blog :

```
< iframe width="140" height="105" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tGzl_AB4poI?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It's all perfect. The only problem is the Audio, because the Volume is too high and I would decrease it-
So I added this part on my code : `"&player.setVolume(5)"`

The final code, then, is this one:

```
< iframe width="140" height="105" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tGzl_AB4poI?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=1&player.setVolume(5)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The problem is that it wont works and the Volume is still the deafault one-
(but the code still works with autoplay and all other pref).

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

In [IFrame API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), you can use [player.setVolume()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setVolume) to set the volume after the player is ready.

If you want to control the volume, you have to write some code in Javascript:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  // iframeId parameter should match your Iframe's id attribute
  var player = new YT.Player('iframeId', {
    width: 140,
    height: 105,
    videoId: 'tGzl_AB4poI',
    events: {
      'onReady': function (event) {
        event.target.setVolume(0);
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
    }
  });
}
```