# Can I control the volume coming out of a specific component in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an iFrame component in my React app, and I am trying to allow the user to control the volume coming out of that component (it is an iFrame). Is there a way to achieve that? This is my iFrame;

```
    <Iframe
      width="100%"
      height={isFull ? "100%" : "450px"}
      src={url}
      frameborder="0"
      allow="fullscreen; accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      styles={{ overflowX: "none" }}
      className={
        isVideoVisible
          ? "my-iframe__content"
          : "my-iframe__content my-iframe__content--invisible"
      }
    />
```

Comment: Is this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/37244586/8681416

Comment: @acbay Thanks but no, my iFrame can contain any website, not just Youtube.